# How to separate the array?

Tags: php, arrays

The following array is coming on $output variable,

```
Array
(
    [title] => Subtotal
    [data] => $1,104.05
)
Array
(
    [title] => Total Shipping
    [data] => $56.45
)
Array
(
    [title] => Order total
    [data] => $1,160.50
)
Array
(
    [border] => top
    [title] => Paying by
    [data] => PayPal
)
```

I want to separate the following array from the above array and want to store it on new variable.
Note:Arrays are coming dynamic.

```
Array
(
    [title] => Order total
    [data] => $1,160.50
)
```

Please help!!

Comment: In **Loop** check if `title === 'Order total'` or not and store accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$array = array(
    Array
(
    [title] => Subtotal
    [data] => $1,104.05
)
Array
(
    [title] => Total Shipping
    [data] => $56.45
)
Array
(
    [title] => Order total
    [data] => $1,160.50
)
Array
(
    [border] => top
    [title] => Paying by
    [data] => PayPal
)
);

$second_array = array();

foreach($array as $key => $arr){
    if(isset($arr['title']) && $arr['title'] === 'Order total'){
        $second_array = $arr;
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

This code will check `title` key is set or not and it's value

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = [
    [
    'title' => 'Subtotal',
    'data' => '$1,104.05'
    ],
    [
    'title' => 'Total Shipping',
    'data' => '$56.45'
    ],
    [
    'title' => 'Order total',
    'data' => '$1,160.50'
    ],
    [
    'border' => 'top',
    'title' => 'Paying by',
    'data' => 'PayPal'
    ]
];


for($i = 0; $i<=count($array); $i){
    if(isset($array[$i]['title']) && $arr[$i]['title'] === 'Order total'){
        $newarr = $arr;
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

```
$array = [
    [
    'title' => 'Subtotal',
    'data' => '$1,104.05'
    ],
    [
    'title' => 'Total Shipping',
    'data' => '$56.45'
    ],
    [
    'title' => 'Order total',
    'data' => '$1,160.50'
    ],
    [
    'border' => 'top',
    'title' => 'Paying by',
    'data' => 'PayPal'
    ]
];

$array = array_filter($array, function($ar) {
   return ($ar['title'] == 'Order total');  //check condition and return record with key
});

$newArray = [];  // your new array
$key = key($array);  // get key of result array
$newArray = $array[$key];  // assign result record to new array
echo "<pre>"; print_r($newArray);
```

**output**:-

```
Array
(
    [title] => Order total
    [data] => $1,160.50
)
```

Hope it will help you :-)